# Laravel 4: img, css, js folders are returning 404

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

For some reason (I've never had this issue before) all of the files that exist in either my `img`, `js`, or `css` folder "dont exist" ... I'm getting a 404 Not Found

Comment: which server? try checking document root setting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include `css/js/etc` stored in `public` folder use `URL::asset` method, i.e.

```
<link href="{{ URL::asset('bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

**Update:** You may also try

```
{{ asset('bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css') }}
```

Here, `bootstrap` folder is inside `domain_root/public` folder.

Comment: Or simply the helper function asset()

Comment: @HaoLuo, Yes, it's also fine.

Comment: No, this isn't working ... it's something strange going on. Everything returns a 404 Not Found.

Comment: Can you check the source of your `css` file and check the `href` ?

Comment: i just created a "style.css" file in my public folder (httpdocs) and I was able to load it ... but then I put the same file within my "css" folder and it returns a 404

Comment: In Laravel's public folder ?

Comment: That's a problem, did you re-assign it's path to the bootstrap process ?

Comment: yes. i did... that's why i dont understand whats going on. i just did tried to modify the permissions of a file within the css folder and im being told that the file doesn't exist... but it does.

Comment: try to undo the changes and try once again for debugging.

Comment: same result as before

Comment: Can you check the `href` of your `css` file in the source ? Where it points to ?

Comment: `{{ asset('css/style.css') }}`

Comment: It's probably a server configuration error ... I'm going to mark this as the correct answer since your solutions should all work. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Welcome and appreciate it :-)

Answer (score 0):

If @Sheikh Heera's answer is not the one you need, best to double-check your `.htaccess` file to ensure it allows existing files through the `index.php` rewrite filter:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Comment: Well, the views load fine ... it's when i try loading any files within the public folder. (which is now httpdocs for my app)